# how print show a text that contains html tags with fast-report?

Tags: html, printing, formatting, report, fastreport

i use of a wysiwyg to get a text of letter with formated like bolde, line break, text-align , ... and save it to my db (msSql)
i have problem when try to print this field with Fast-Report!

---

saved value in DB :

```
line1 <br/> line2 <br/>line3
```

on print must show like this:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

but fast-report show like this:

```
line1 <br/> line2 <br/>line3
```

---

i set propery of text object in fast-report:

```
Wysiwyg = true
HtmlTags = true
```

but not true!
please help me

Comment: fast report does not support html tags

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says:

> Tags are **disabled by default**; to enable them, either select the "Allow
>   HTML tags" item in the object context menu, or **enable the**
>   **"AllowHTMLTags" property** in the object inspector.

Here is the list of supported tags:

```
<b> - bold text
<i> - text in italic
<u> - underlined text
<sub> - subscript
<sup> - superscript
<font color> - font color
```

To get more information check out this link to documentation:

[HTML-tags in the "Text" object](https://www.fast-report.com/en/documentation/frx3user/Creating%20reports/HTML-tags%20in%20the%20'Text'%20object.htm)